# can't complete the function on chainshot

Tags: javascript

i'm new to js and started trying to learn code with chainshot
there's a simple task that I can't pass:

Task description

Let's complete the `isEqual` function! If `a` is equal to `b` return `true`.

my code

```
function isEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) {
    console.log(" true ");
    }
}

export default isEqual;
```

[image: error return in this screen]

Comment: "console.log(" true ");" this should be `return true`, better yet the function could be written simply as `function isEqual(a, b) {return a === b}`, and for your infos when a function doesn't explicitly return something it implicitly returns `undefined`

Comment: but there's a requirement to use ```if``` statement

Comment: Then use an if statement and return instead of logging `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return true, instead of using console.log, and return false if a wasnt equal to b. `console.log` doesnt return a value, it just shows it on the console, as it's name suggest. Use the keyword return for that, and return the keyword `true` or `false` instead of a string, since you're expecting a boolean.

```js
function isEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
export default isEqual;
```

You can simplify the function by just returning `a === b`, like

```js
function isEqual(a, b) {
    return a === b;
}
export default isEqual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return boolean value. But in your code function doesn't return any.

```js
function isEqual(a, b) {
    return a === b;
}
export default isEqual;
```

Comment: but i don't see any ```if``` statement in your code, but i think that was a "must use"

Comment: The result of comparison operator `===` is boolean. Your function should return boolean. Try to `console.log(1===0)` and `console.log(1===1)`.

Answer (score 0):

What website are you running that on? It worked for me.
Here is a simpler version of the code you're trying to do:

```
function isEqual(a, b) {
  return a === b
}
```

Comment: https://www.chainshot.com/content/5c492009e714340017be6e1d5d7feb8309d5ed335cbf092c/stage/5c492009e714340017be6e1d5d7febe809d5ed335cbf092d